# When did Access control list (ACL) come to Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, acl

When did *ACL* get included into Unix/Linux ?

And why ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list

Answer (score 0):

Traditional UNIX/Linux divided everyone on Earth into three groups:

1. The *owner* of the file.  This is usually the file creator.
2. The *team* of the owner.  This is usually other members on the same project so they can share files easily.
3. Everyone else who can get access to the system.

As UNIX/Linux moved to larger platforms, and gained a larger user complement, the original groupings did not allow enough flexibility to manage users, auditors, developers, production streams, and on all the rest.  ACL is a bolt-on accessory used to implement this fine level of resource control.

ACLs have been around for a long, long time; I first encountered ACLs way back in the late 70's and they show up everywhere.  Must have been a good idea.